# WebGL Animation Optimization

Tags: performance, svg, pagespeed

I have a simple React application that uses SVG animation library (Vanta.js) and Vanta.js itself uses three.js under the hood.

I tested my website performance on Google PageSpeed Insights, GtMetrix, Pingdom etc. My page load time is below than 3 seconds, total page size under 250kb, the total request is 10, so my overall performance score is 85+.

However, **Google PageSpeed Insight** says completely different things (Score: 30):

Speed Index: 5s

Time To Interactive: 35s

First CPU Idle: 35s

Main Issues:

- Minimize main-thread work (no detailed explanation)
- Efficient cache policy (for all my assets)
- Reduce JS execution time (vanta.js library and whole webpack bundle)

I used CDN for JS libraries (Vanta and Three) nothing changed. Now, I imported js libraries and I don't fetch them from CDN. I imported a google font with @font-face. What else can I do? I think the main problem is about SVG animation libraries or SVG.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience vantajs is a real performance killer. i am currently writing a rails application that uses vanta and when i remove the library my speed index increases by 20. probably you are already working on the next project but try to systematically remove certain libraries to get the source of the problem.